# jQuery ajax corporate environment

Tags: jquery, ajax

i developed a web application in HTML5 and jquery, the jquery calls go my webservice (asmx) located for e.g. http://mysite.com/service1.asmx

everything woks fine from most places. however, last week i tried to demo the software to someone behind a corporate firewall.

the question i had was is there anything incorrect my service url when combined with jquery ajax?

Using jQuery, HTML5, ASP.NET, C#, WebServices

Comment: Behind a corporate firewall, anything is possible. In all seriousness, your call could be perfect, but it could be blocked for some reason. Ask the IT people if you have continued issues.

Comment: It's likely that one of the external domains used by your application is being blocked. This is easily tested using firebug or google chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here.  My first guess is that the web service site is blocked while inside the corporate network.  Use the developer tools of a browser and track down what is happening with the AJAX call when you are in the corporate environment.  The Google Chrome Developer tools has a Network panel which would be perfect for this.  Another possibility is that you are violating the browser's [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for your web service domain.